# What should be the SQL query to get the desired result?

Tags: sql

My Table is as follows :-

```
messageid recipientid   senderid  senderfirstname       message
121         110           104           Noah            hii !!
122         110           111           Adam            heyy... wots up ??
123         104           115           Emeline         hello..
124         104           110           Eliana          abc
125         111           110           Eliana          yup 
126         115           110           Eliana          xyz
127         110           104           Noah            where are you ?
```

I want the output as :-

```
messageid recipientid   senderid  senderfirstname      message
127             110         104          Noah          where are you ?
122             110         111          Adam          heyy... wots up ??
```

I want to get all the messages received by recipient 110 , but i need to fetch the latest records by the same user .

I need the last record      but not the first one as the last one is latest by "Noah" .

What SQL query should I write to achieve the same ?

Comment: on what `clause` do u want to query the output????

Comment: Care to explain what is the logic involved?

Comment: I want to get all the messages received by recipient 110 , but i need to fetch the latest records by the same user ., i need the last record      but not the first one as the last one is latest by "Noah"

Comment: :( its still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you explained in the comments section to your request what you are looking for, here is a way to achieve this: You select all records with recipientid 110, but only take one reocrd per senderid (GROUP BY), namely the highest messageid (MAX). With these mesage ids found you retrieve the complete records.

```
select *
from thetable
where messageid in
(
  select max(messageid)
  from thetable
  where recipientid = 110
  group by senderid
)
order by senderid;
```

Comment: I think you just should order by messageid DESC

Comment: @user3346815 : mention question properly next time and mark answer accepted if it worked!! :)

Comment: yup i will @NoobEditor.. :)

Comment: @CodeBird: No. We select all senders with their last message. It is pure coincidence that in the example given the message ids are in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read up on sql queries.

```
SELECT `messageid`, `recipientid`, `senderid`, `senderfirstname`, `message` FROM `table` WHERE (condition) ORDER BY `messageid` DESC
```

Comment: This will return everything, with the messageid in descending order.

Comment: Yes, I know, he should really explain what he needs, I have added the condition example, since what really would be the filter is really inconclusive, but it does not seem that hard.